# What is `wasted space` parameter and why is it O(n) for a linked list

Tags: data-structures, arrays, linked-lists

I'm reading a book on data structures and there is a comparison between linked list, array and dynamic array. The parameter name is *wasted space*. Here are the values:

\begin{array}{cc}
    \text{Linked list} & O(n)\\
    \text{array}        & 0 \\
    \text{dynamic array}& O(n)
\end{array}

What is the wasted space parameter and why is it $O(n)$ for a linked list?

Comment: While I've actually never seen "wasted space" defined as a term, it may be useful to contrast to the concepts of [implicit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_data_structure) and [succinct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succinct_data_structure) data structures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different people seem to define "wasted space" in different ways. Some authors define it as any space in a data structure that's not used to store actual data; others define it as space that could be used to store data but isn't being so used at the moment.

So, in the first definition, a linked list has $O(n)$ wasted space because every entry of the list contains some piece of data but also a pointer, so a constant fraction of the space taken up by the data structure is "wasted". (I think this is a silly definition of "waste": the space taken up by the pointers isn't wasted; it's an overhead.)  In the second definition, a half-full hash-table has 50% wasted space (again, $O(n)$).

Comment: thanks, so it's a space complexity, correct?

Comment: It's a measure of space usage. I hesitate to use the word "complexity" as that normally refers to the resource requirements to decide a particular language, which isn't quite what we mean, here.

Comment: I don't understand then why it's also `O(n)` for a dynamic array, can you please clarify? Dynamic array usually holds only a pointer to the beginning for an array and some boolean indicator whether an array is full or not.

Comment: @Maximus Because, when a dynamic array is full, its size is increased by some factor $\alpha$. This means that, immediately after growing, a dynamic array holding $n$ items has size about $n\alpha$, so the amount of wasted space is $n(\alpha-1) = O(n)$.