# Does array always have a wasted space of O(n)?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, data-structures, arrays, space-analysis

[In this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74434/70982) it's stated that dynamic array wasted space is O(n). [Here is](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74434/what-is-wasted-space-parameter-and-why-is-it-on-for-a-linked-list/74435?noredirect=1#comment159509_74435) the explanation why:

> Because, when a dynamic array is full, its size is increased by some
>   factor `α`. This means that, immediately after growing, a dynamic array
>   holding `n` items has size about nαnα, so the amount of wasted space is
>   `n(α−1)=O(n)n(α−1)=O(n)`.

I'm wondering if it's always `O(n)`. Maybe there is some logic similar [to this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74918/70982) which proves that wasted space is not `O(n)`?

Comment: How do you want to define "wasted space"? In particular? Worst case or average case? Amortised?

Comment: You can use virtual memory which eliminates the memory waste upon array resize, so no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the algorithm used. Someone made the assumption that when an array has space for n items, and the n+1st item needs to be added, the array would be resized to a size c·n for some constant c > 1. But there is nothing forcing us to do this; we could resize from n items to f (n) items, where f (n) ≥ n+1 obviously but f (n) - n = o (n).